# NoClassDefFoundError JIRA REST API

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, jira

I am new to JIRA I downloaded m2e plugin for eclipse Indigo and JIRA 5.0 version

```
public class JIRAClient { 
       public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {  
           final JerseyJiraRestClientFactory factory = new JerseyJiraRestClientFactory();
           final URI jiraServerUri = new URI("http://jira.travelclick.net:8080/jira/rest/api"); 

Exception---> final JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, "nsrivastava", "Password12");

           final NullProgressMonitor pm = new NullProgressMonitor();    
           final Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue("TST-1", pm);
           System.out.println(issue);          

           } 
       }
```

I have following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpConnectionManager
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyJiraRestClientFactory.create(JerseyJiraRestClientFactory.java:34)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyJiraRestClientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(JerseyJiraRestClientFactory.java:39)
    at client.JIRAClient.main(JIRAClient.java:24)
```

I also downloaded commons-logging-1.1.1.jar file here is my classpath file(created by eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/bhaviksh/Downloads/httpcomponents-client-4.2.2-bin/httpcomponents-client-4.2.2/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

This would be my first program I dont even know what JIRA exactly is yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the API you are using requires Jakarta Commons' HTTPClient at *runtime*. Is commons-httpclient included in your runtime classpath? (you don't need it for compilation)

Comment: no it is not but I cannot find the jar file for that. I downloaded a HttpClient jar from this link http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi but tis does not contain commons-httpclient